# phpflickr : photos_search doesn't find photos just after upload

Tags: phpflickr

I use the phpflickr api for a project and I have a weird problem : when I upload a photo (with sync_upload), and that I use a photo_search just after the upload, the function doesn't find the photo. I I use photo_search 5 to 10 seconds after the upload, it works, like if there was an indexing time in flickr.

I use machine_tags to find the photo, I don't know if it could be the source of the problem.

Someone have an idea to solve the problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Sandrino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and testing, I think my method using photo_search was not the right one.

My purpose was retrieving my photos only and it seems to be more relevant to use the function photos_getInfo with the id of the photo in parameter.

The original question of the delay problem of the photo_search function is not yet resolved, so I will leave this question open for few days in case someone would informations about this problem.

Thank you.